# How to think of an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, open-map

I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly "open ball" means when it comes to dealing with subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, and likely by extension any metric space.

Consider the subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, $$A = \{(x,y) : x+y=1\}$$ $$B = \{(x,y) : x,y\in\mathbb Q\}.$$

> Let $\langle M,\rho\rangle$ be a metric space. If $a\in M$ and $r>0$, then the open ball of radius $r$ about $a$, $B(a;r)$, is defined as $$B(a;r) = \{x\in M : \rho(x,a) < r\}.$$

I'm wondering how to determine whether or not these sets are open/closed. We say that a subset $G$ of $M$ is open if for every $x\in G$, there exists a number $r>0$ such that the entire open ball $B(x;r)$ is contained in $G$.

So when considering a subset of a metric space, can an open ball of $G$ contain points of $M$ that are outside of $G$? For example, consider the picture:

[image]

This is an image of a line such as the one in $A$. Is the open ball the yellow and purple space, or is it *just* the purple part?

The definition is just a little confusing to me.

Comment: Just curious,,, Why are you studying this

Comment: The open ball is constructed so that it will be open, although that has to be proved in the topology. Also, it depends on what $\rho$ is. If you are talking about the standard metric, then the yellow part is the ball of radius $r$ around the point $x$, while the purple part is just it's intersection with some line passing through $x$ (has no contextual significance)

Comment: We usually say "the open ball in $X$" when we want to avoid ambiguity. Under this language, it always means the points of the ball are in $X$. Often, the context is clear, and we don't need to specify "in $X$."

Comment: The line $A$ as a subset of the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the usual metric) is not open. Indeed, pick any point on the line and consider any open ball centered about this point. Then there are points in the ball that do not belong to the line. Hence there aren't even open balls contained in $A$. So surely $A$ cannot be open by definition. The picture you added shows all these things.

Comment: @anonymous, I don't consider the set $B$ because I think the logic will be similar if I understand the logic for the set $A$.

Comment: This depends on whether you speak of an open ball contained in the subset A of M, or of an open ball of the subspace A (for the induced metric). In the first case, your subset has no open ball contained in it, in the second case, it is the purple interval (open ball of A).  As to the yellow disc, it's an open ball of M.

Comment: @Mathematician42 which by that same logic, that means that $B$ is not open either because we know that between any two rationals, there exists an irrational number. Thus any open ball in $B$ contains points outside of $B$ (irrational points).

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: It seems to me that the source of your confusion comes from the fact that you are not considering that the property of a set "being open" depends to respect to which metric space. For instance, in your example, both A and B are not open (A is closed, B is not closed) in $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual metric. That corresponds to considering the yellow circle as your open ball in the picture. However, every set is both open and closed; in particular A is both open and close with respect to A; this corresponds to considering the open ball as the purple line in your picture.

Comment: @Masacroso open balls need not be convex. We can define open balls in any metric space, which need not have a vector space structure on it.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist right! My bad. Thank you for the correction.